# Прокрута блоков сайта горизонтально по кнопкам

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно ли реализовать прокрутку блоков сайта по нажатию на кнопки, используя только ванильный JS или CSS?
Возможно, вопрос не совсем корректный, так как я не совсем понимаю как это называется.
Чтобы изобразить свои мысли более понятно, прибегу к очевидному примеру: при нажатии кнопки About появится один блок, при нажатии на Home пролистывается к другому.
Если вопрос всё равно не совсем понятный, не требую прямого решения проблемы, но нужна хотя бы наводка, куда двигаться чтобы реализовать идею.

Comment: Если есть простое решение с использованием JQuery - тоже подойдёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('a[data-id]').click(function() {
    const block_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    const block = $(`.block[data-id=${block_id}]`);
    const offsetLeft = block.offset().left;
    $(".container").animate({scrollLeft: offsetLeft}, 1000, "swing");
});
```

```css
.container{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.block{
  width: 75vw;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" data-id="1">
    <h2>First slide</h2>
    <a href="#!" data-id="3">to 3 slide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block" data-id="2">
    <h2>Two slide</h2>
    <a href="#!">Non slide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block" data-id="3">
    <h2>Three slide</h2>
    <a href="#!" data-id="1">to first slide</a>
  </div>
  <div class="block" data-id="4">
    <h2>Four slide</h2>
    <a href="#!">Non slide</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скролл к блоку:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: block.offset().top});
```

Ну а навесить события - думаю, и так всё понятно

Comment: Горизонтальный же скролл требуется, а не вертикальный. Хоть бы вопрос читали внимательно :(

Comment: @humster_spb, Ок, тогда так:
`$("html, body").animate({scrollLeft: 58});`
Если нужен скролл внутри блока, то `$(block).animate({scrollLeft: какое_то_значение});`

Comment: так в чем проблема переделать данный вариант под себя? Там менять то и не особо много, изучили бы для начала данный скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollTo(desiredElement) { //передаете нужный элемент, до которого хотите прокрутить, как аргумент desiredElement
    const distance = desiredElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset; //расстояние от начала документа по оси X до нужного нам элемента
    window.srollTo(distance ,0); //скролимся до этого элемента
}
```

чистый JS. ну и вешаете обработчик клика и передаете ему эту функцию. должно, вроде бы, сработать. если хотите плавный переход, то используйте `requestAnimationFrame`.
и да, может и не работать, так как проверить пока не могу :D